# Really confused about snippets

Tags: scala, lift

I have a problem with my lift view. The thing is, I am making an expensive remote rest-api call twice - where I should really need to do it only once.

But I can't figure out how to solve this.

Basically I have an HTML template like this, that needs to display the list of users and their count:

```
//UserSearchResults.html

Num users: <span class="lift:UserSearchResults.userCount"></span>

User list:
<ul>
<lift:UserSearchResults.userList>   
   <li><user:userName/></li>
</lift:UserSearchResults.userList>    
</ul>
```

And then I have an actual snippet that goes and retrieves the list of users from the rest-api server. However, note that it actually does this TWICE - once to count the number of users, and once to render the list.

```
  //UserSearchResults.scala 

  /** Get list of users from api */
  def users: List[User] = {
    val url = "http://server/rest-api/user-search";
    val result = io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

    //... parse users into List[User] and return it

    return entries
  }

  /** Render user count */
  def userCount =
    "* *" #> users.length    //<-- ONE call

  def userList(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    users.flatMap(user => Helpers.bind("user", in,  //<--SECOND call
      "userName" -> user.user_name)) 
  }
```

Is there a better place to put the api call? Is there like a "constructor" for the snippet, that I can use cache the user list, and to share it across all the functions in the class?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If UserSearchResults is a class (as opposed to an object), then there will be a per-request instance of that class. As such, all you have to do is change your def users to a lazy val users and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Is there a way to get by without "lazy" (I didn't read about that scala feature yet)?

Comment: @drozzy `lazy val` defines a value that will only be computed when its value is used and is guaranteed to only be calculated once. It's perfect for this situation.

Comment: P.S.: Anytime you feel like answering scala/lift questions look up my profile - I always have a bunch of dumb ones nobody seems to want to answer!

Comment: Hehe. Will do.

As Bill points out, lazy val is probably useful in this case. It's a way of memoizing a result. If you're familiar with Ruby or JS, it's the same as saying `variable = variable || < function that computes the variable's value >', only thread-safe and all better.

That said, if you need the relevant values every time that snippet is used, you can just make it a regular val and you'll be fine. By the way, you can do a whole block to determine the initial value of a variable or a lazy val, so no syntax has to change.

Answer (score 0):

If your snippet extends StatefulSnippet, you can just save the list in an instance variable. Another option would be to put the list into a RequestVar. Then it could also be accessed from other snippets.